# Redirect website to another website if blocked in particular region

Tags: redirect, web, dns, subdomain, url-routing

One of my client website is blocked in UAE, how can I redirect UAE users to another website if current website is blocked?
for example: www.abc.com is accessible to the world but not UAE.
I want UAE users to redirect to another website (i.e. www.xyz.com) if www.abc.com is blocked in their region.

Comment: How is it being blocked?

Comment: website is for legal purpose which is applicable with international law but not with UAE. We want to redirect UAE users to different site that would provide services according to UAE law.

Comment: Is it being redirected to a catch site? Or blackhole routed? What actual mechanism are they using to block the traffic?

Comment: Don't know, URL remain same in address bar but title of tab is changed and there is a message on page.

Comment: Some quick googling indicates that they may be using a proxy mechanism. If it's a proxy intercept that's sitting on the outbound paths from the UAE, then you would likely need to modify the DNS response for www.abc.com to another service inside the UAE with your xyz.com content. If you can learn more about the mechanism they're using to intercept the traffic, that would likely lead to a much better answer.