# My website is blocked in Dubai, is possible to redirect to another domain?

Tags: php

My website is blocked in UAE (Dubai). So, is there any way to redirect to another domain in UAE country only. This same question is already asked at [Redirect website to another website if blocked in particular region](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782825/redirect-website-to-another-website-if-blocked-in-particular-region). But there i could not find any solution. is any solution available?

i have tried with redirection code

```
<?php
 function ip_visitor_country()
{
    $CountryCode  = "Unknown";

       if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
         $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
       $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } else {
       $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
      }


    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=".$ip);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $ip_data_in = curl_exec($ch); // string
    curl_close($ch);

    $ip_data = json_decode($ip_data_in,true);
    $ip_data = str_replace('&quot;', '"', $ip_data); // for PHP 5.2 see stackoverflow.com/questions/3110487/

    if($ip_data && $ip_data['geoplugin_countryCode'] != null) {
       $CountryCode = $ip_data['geoplugin_countryCode'];
    }


    return $CountryCode;
}

//echo ip_visitor_country(); // output Coutry code

if(ip_visitor_country()=="AE"){header("Location: http://www.example.com");exit();}
?>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398674/get-users-current-location

Comment: How are they going to get to the redirect if they can't get to the site?

Comment: then what was the solution for that?

Comment: @Habibunishayaseen There's not a great solution here. If the UAE is banning your site, they're likely to ban its replacement. In the meantime, you don't have a technological approach here - you'd have to get out the word to UAE folks to use a different domain (or some sort of out-of-country VPN/proxy).